# GraphQL query with Apollo Client is returning an empty response

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, subscription

i'm trying to connect graphal after adding websocket and subscription to react but all reauest are returnin empty array with nod data
here is my server.js

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
import { getUser, userProtect ,adminProtect,getAdmin} from "./Users/user.utilities.js";
import { typeDefs, resolvers } from './schema.js';
// import GraphQlUpload from 'graphql-upload'
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';
import { graphqlUploadExpress,GraphQLUpload} from "graphql-upload";
import * as path  from 'path';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';
import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    path: '/graphql'
});

const wsServerCleanup = useServer({schema}, wsServer);

const startApolloServer = async () => {
  app.use(graphqlUploadExpress())
  app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/images')))

const context = async ({ req }) => {

  return {
    LogedInUser: await getUser(req.headers.token),
    LogedInAdmin: await getAdmin(req.headers.admintoken),
    userProtect,
    adminProtect
  }
}
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    plugins: [
   
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      {
        async requestDidStart({ contextValue }) {
          // token is properly inferred as a string
          console.log(contextValue.token);
        },
      },
      {
       async serverWillStart() {
           return {
               async drainServer() {
                   await wsServerCleanup.dispose();
               }
           }
       }
      }
   ],
  
  })
 
  
  await server.start();
  
 
  app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), expressMiddleware(server,{ context }));

}
startApolloServer()
httpServer.listen(8000, () => { console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000$`) })
  ;
```

and here is my apollo.js in react

```
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { makeVar } from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({ 
  uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql" });
const authLink = setContext((_,{headers })=>{
return{
  headers:{
    ...headers,
    token:localStorage.getItem(TOKEN),
    admintoken:localStorage.getItem(ADMINTOKE)
  }
}



})
export const client = new ApolloClient({
   link:authLink.concat(uploadLink) ,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
```

i face this problem only after adding subscriptions to server.js in nodejs

[it works in studio sandbox but not in client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlhcE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyw1G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my server after

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
  dotenv.config()
  import { getUser, userProtect ,adminProtect,getAdmin} from "./Users/user.utilities.js";
  import { typeDefs, resolvers } from './schema.js';
  // import GraphQlUpload from 'graphql-upload'
  import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
  import { createServer } from 'http';
  import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
  import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
  import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
  import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
  import express from 'express';
  import { graphqlUploadExpress,GraphQLUpload} from "graphql-upload";
  import * as path  from 'path';
  import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
  import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';
  import { PubSub } from 'graphql-subscriptions';
  import cors from 'cors';
  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = createServer(app);
  
  const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
      server: httpServer,
      path: '/graphql'
  });
  
  const wsServerCleanup = useServer({schema}, wsServer);
  
  const startApolloServer = async () => {
    app.use(graphqlUploadExpress())
    app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/images')))
  
  const context = async ({ req }) => {
  console.log(req.headers.token)
    return {
      LogedInUser: await getUser(req.headers.token),
      LogedInAdmin: await getAdmin(req.headers.admintoken),
      userProtect,
      adminProtect
    }
  }
    const server = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      plugins: [
     
        ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
       
      
        {
         async serverWillStart() {
             return {
                 async drainServer() {
                     await wsServerCleanup.dispose();
                 }
             }
         }
        }
     ],
    
    })
   
    
    await server.start();
    
   
    app.use('/graphql',cors(), bodyParser.json(), expressMiddleware(server,{ context }));
  
  }
  startApolloServer()
  httpServer.listen(8000, () => { console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000$`) })
    ;
```

and here is my apollo client in react

```js
import { makeVar } from "@apollo/client";
import { setContext } from "@apollo/client/link/context";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { GraphQLWsLink } from '@apollo/client/link/subscriptions';
import { createClient } from 'graphql-ws';
import { split, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { getMainDefinition } from '@apollo/client/utilities';
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";


const TOKEN = "token"
const ADMINTOKE="admintoken"
export const isLogedIn = makeVar(Boolean(localStorage.getItem(TOKEN)
));
export const AdminisLogedIn = makeVar(Boolean(localStorage.getItem(ADMINTOKE)
));
export const Dark = makeVar(false)

export const AdminLogIn = (admintoken) =>{
  localStorage.setItem(ADMINTOKE , admintoken)
  AdminisLogedIn(true)
}
export const AdminLogOut = () =>{
  localStorage.removeItem(ADMINTOKE)
  AdminisLogedIn(false)
 
}
export const UserLogIn = (token) =>{
  localStorage.setItem(TOKEN , token)
  isLogedIn(true)
}
export const UserLogOut = () =>{
  localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN)
  isLogedIn(false)
 
}
const wsLink = new GraphQLWsLink(createClient({
  url: 'ws://localhost:8000/graphql',
}));

const uploadLink = createUploadLink({ 
  uri: "http://localhost:8000/graphql" });
const authLink = setContext((_,{headers })=>{
return{
  headers:{
    ...headers,
    token:localStorage.getItem(TOKEN),
    admintoken:localStorage.getItem(ADMINTOKE)
  }
}



})


const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  uploadLink,
);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(splitLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).